# J2ME widget library

Tags: user-interface, java-me

I am starting to develop a J2ME app and the built-in GUI components of the java library are ugly and inflexible.

Can anyone recommend a nice and easy to use (open-source...) widget library?

Comment: A related question in the j2me tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116394/java-me-ui-libraries

Answer (score 4):

Not too many choices out there. The best option is probably Sun's [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/). It's recently been GPL'ed. Alternatively you can go with [J2ME Polish](http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/), which is licensed under GPL and commercially depending on what you are doing with it.

Our company is probably going to go with LWUIT. Seems likely that it will be the best-supported API in the future.