# Java ME libraries

Tags: java-me

Java ME is quite sparse on features. Are there any libraries you use to add missing features?

I don't want to focus on UI libraries - these are better discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116394/java-me-ui-libraries). I am aware of that there exists [JSRs](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/tech?listBy=1&listByType=platform) with optional features.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of Java ME JSRs that have actually been implemented in shipped handsets or a list of non-standard but publicly documented J2ME extensions?

Comment: @Quick: I already have a list of JSRs. I am looking for any other libraries that add features people would generally expect in a programming language into Java ME. Then again, if there are any libraries that allow use of a JSR on a phone that doesn't actually support the JSR, then this would be interesting as well.

Comment: I think Vivart attempted an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460453/some-userful-3rd-party-apis-for-j2me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some useful stuff at [j4me.org](http://code.google.com/p/j4me/).

Comment: This adds some missing maths functions, plus logging, bluetooth gps and a new gui library.

Answer (score 3):

For various crypto functions, The Legion of the Bouncy Castle [Lightweight API](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) for J2ME.

Answer (score 1):

Java ME was intentionally designed to be based on JDK 1.3, so yes it is quite old and sparse. But a lot of handset manufacturers (like Nokia) have their custom API that provide some valuable functionality.

There are ways to provide support to more standard Java like features like enums by using tools like Retroweaver, which allow us to compile them with Java ME.

I have also heard that J2ME Polish like frameworks have custom implementations that are more sophisticated. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for RetroWeaver. Using the custom API for a particular handset will take away a lot of the advantage of using Java ME

Answer (score 1):

The Microlog logging library is a quite handy library for logging:

http://microlog.microsuite.org/